# Struggling to install react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im struggling to follow the steps which react has set out for me. Ive tried installing and uninstalling node a few times at this point.
when i type in npm i get 'npm.cmd' failed to run:
Npx
ResourceUnavailable: Program 'npx.cmd' failed to run:

Comment: Did you try running `npm install -g npx@latest`?

Comment: windows or mac ?

Comment: im on windows..

Comment: PS C:\Users\Brandon> npm install -g npx@latest
ResourceUnavailable: Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd' with working directory 'C:\Users\Brandon'. The system cannot find the file specified.At line:1 char:1
+ npm install -g npx@latest
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.

Comment: I tried your suggestion unfortunately it didnt work

Comment: try, `npm --version` and let see the output

Comment: Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: The system cannot find the file specifiedAt line:1 char:1
+ npm --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed